# Geometric sequences , cones and cylinders

Tags: sequences-and-series

I’ve come across an interesting problem where a square is constructed within a circle , we then construct the circle inscribed within the previous square and so on.

The idea the problem discusses is that the areas of the squares are a geometric sequence, and the areas of the circles are as well a geometric sequence.

[image: This is an illustration of the problem]

What I'm searching for is a similar problem with an illustration where we have, instead of squares and circles, cylinders and spheres or cylinders and cones; and where we discuss volumes instead of areas.

For clarification :
I want a similar problem with an illustration where we discuss volumes instead of areas . (For instance we construct a cylinder within a sphere and then a sphere within a cylinder and so on)

Note :
I am new to SE, so I don’t know if this question violates the rules.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please do check out [the rules](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). I think this question could be improved with a little more clarity, both about the original 2D question and the 3D question, and what you want from us. Do you want us to provide a similar question in 3D? Do you want a solution to such a problem? Would you be happy with an explanation as to why such similar problems will result in geometric sequences?

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: I want  to be provided with a similar question in 3D

Comment: I still would be happy if I were provided with an explanation of why such problem result in geometric sequences.

Comment: @Alo But not a solution to such a question?

Comment: No , I have the solution

Comment: You've mentioned such a similar problem in your question (the cylinder one). So what kind of similar problem do you want? It's supposed to be restricted a bit.

Comment: I ask if there were a cylinder /cone problem or any 3D version of such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be happy to oblige you with an explanation about why these questions (if I understand their scope correctly) will always result in a geometric series. The questions, as I see them, involve inscribing shape $B$ into shape $A$, then inscribing $A$ into the copy of $B$, then inscribing $B$ into that copy of $A$, etc, etc. Each copy of shape $A$ has to be *similar*, as indeed must be the copies of $B$.

By "similar", I mean the mathematical term in geometry, which means that the two shapes can be identified by a process of scaling (i.e. stretching or shrinking the shape uniformly in all directions), and then applying an isometry (i.e. a map that preserves distances and angles, such as rotation, translation, reflection, etc). For example, all square no matter what size are similar, but no square is similar to a rectangle that is not a square.

It will also help if we are looking for the largest copy of $B$ that we can put in $A$, and vice-versa. Under these circumstances, we will always get a geometric series.

Now, let's suppose we have two shapes $A$ and $A'$ in $n$ dimensions (could be $2$ or $3$, or more, or even just $1$). This means we must be able to scale $A$, then move/rotate/reflect it until it becomes $A'$. The moving/rotating/reflecting will not change the volume of $A$, but the scaling will. Let's say we scale by a factor of $\lambda$. Then, in $n$ dimensions, the new volume of $A'$ will change by a factor of $\lambda$. That is,
$$\operatorname{Vol} A' = \lambda^n \operatorname{Vol} A.$$
For example, if $A$ is a sphere of radius $1$ in $3$ dimensions, and $A'$ is a sphere of radius $2$ in $3$ dimensions, then $A'$ has $2^3 = 8$ times the volume of $A$.

I claim that, if we inscribe similar shapes $B$ and $B'$ into $A$ and $A'$ respectively, each with maximum volume, then $\operatorname{Vol} B' = \lambda^n \operatorname{Vol} B$. If say $\operatorname{Vol} B' < \lambda^n \operatorname{Vol} B$, then applying whatever scaling/rotation/reflection/translation operations were necessary to take $A$ to $A'$ to $B$ instead will yield a shape $B''$, similar to $B$, inscribed in $A'$. Because the volume is determined by the scaling factor, which was $\lambda$, we have
$$\operatorname{Vol} B'' = \lambda^n \operatorname{Vol} B > \operatorname{Vol} B'.$$
This contradicts $B'$ being the largest copy of $B$ inside $A'$.

A similar contradiction can be worked out when $\operatorname{Vol} B' > \lambda^n \operatorname{Vol} B$. Since each scaling/rotation/reflection/translation operation can be reversed, this is really just a symmetric case, switching the roles of $A, B$ and $A', B'$.

Of course, now when we look at putting copies of $A$ into $B$, we get another scaling factor, let's call it $\mu^n$. Now, once a copy $A'$ of $A$ is placed into a copy of $B$, which is in $A$, we see that the volume of $A'$ is scaled by a factor $\mu^n \lambda^n$. Since $A'$ is similar to $A$, the next copy down (call it $A''$?) will be multiplied by the same factor $\mu^n \lambda^n$, etc, etc. In this way, we get a geometric sequence, with common ratio $\mu^n \lambda^n$. The volumes of the $B$s will also form a geometric sequence similarly, with the same common ratio.

The tricky bit is finding $\lambda$ and $\mu$! This will depend on the specific shapes you're considering.